# ¿Por qué me marca este error y como solucionarlo en PHP y JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo esta función en JS a la cual le tengo que pasar dos variables a través de un botón que viene de un formulario HTML el cual es un login donde pido usuario y contraseña, pero desde que cargo la página me marca este error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" en la linea 2 y me gustaría saber por qué o que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<script>
$(function(){
 LoginApp();
});
 $url = 'http://servidor/api/AppWeb/Login_User';
 function LoginApp(String $usuario, String $pass){
 $data = array('usuario' => usuario, 'pass' => pass);
 $options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$datos=json_decode($result,true);
var_dump($result);
}
 </script>
```

He hecho los cambios incluso les agrego la parte de mi formulario en html del inicio de sesión, cual es la finalidad, que al momento de que el usuario haga su logueo, los datos se envien a la función y esta función valide en un API los datos. Igual me gustaría saber si estoy haciendo bien el llamado de la función y el envío de los datos

```
 <div>
        <input type="text"  id="usuario" placeholder="Ingresa usuario" 
  class="form-control my-3" >
        <input type="password"  id="pass" placeholder="Ingresa contraseña" 
  class="form-control my-3">
        <input  class="btn btn-primary" id="boton" type="button" 
   onclick="LoginApp('$usuario', '$pass')"></input>
   </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Es la versión 5.5.12

Comment: TODOS los usos de TODAS las variables deben tener el `$` antepuesto, no sólo la declaración al comienzo. EL tipo de dato String tampoco va

Comment: @BetaM no sé, no creo... habrá muchas personas novatas que encuentran tutoriales de versiones nuevas y le pegan a todo, sin saber que en versiones viejas pasan estas cosas. Que alguien con más poder en la etiqueta PHP decida :)

Comment: Ya he hecho los cambios que me comentaron, pero sigo  con el mismo error en consola

Comment: Ya se lo he cambiado, lo puse en minúsculas y ya probé también quitándoselo, pero me marca ese error, incluso desde que refresco esa página me marca ese error

Comment: ¿Dónde abres y cierras las etiquetas `<?php` y `?>` para mostrar HTML y volver al intérprete?

Comment: No abro ninguna etiqueta de esas amigo, en dónde tendría que hacerlo?

Comment: Como comentario final, desde _Javascript_ no puedes ejecutar una función de _PHP_, porque trabajan en contextos diferentes y no puede haber esa interacción, a menos que lo hagas con una petición AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas abrir la etiqueta `<?php` para entrar al "modo intérprete" de *PHP* y cerrar `?>` para entrar al "modo HTML":

```
<?php
// Inicio de script y definición de funciones, variables, etc.
// En PHP < 7 no puedes definir tipo de dato en los parámetros
function LoginApp($usuario, $pass){
    $url = 'http://servidor/api/AppWeb/Login_User';
    $data = array('usuario' => usuario, 'pass' => pass);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $datos=json_decode($result,true);
    var_dump($result);
}

// Ejecutar la función directamente en PHP
LoginAPP('nombre-usuario', 'contraseña');

// Entrar al modo HTML:
?>
<script src="url-para-cargar/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    // Aquí tu código Javascript,
    // que no puede ejecutar directamente funciones de PHP
    // En todo caso, deberías usar AJAX
});
</script>
<?php // Volver al modo PHP
// Más código si es necesario
```

Answer (score 0):

usuario y pass no deberían tener `$` antepuesto? Y por lo que veo en el sitio de php, es `string` con s minuscula.

Comment: Ya le agregué el signo y aún así me sigue marcado ese error